# Disable all svn auto checks in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, svn

I'm not sure if this is an intellij version control or SVN issue, but is there a way to disable all auto subversion / version control update checks in Intellij?

When you click the version control tab at the bottom of the IDE and look at local changes, the lists often say "Updating...".

I want to use subversion, but for huge projects the "updating" in intellij version control sometimes takes a good 10 minutes, and it starts randomly for no reason, even when I have not made changes. I checked the settings and I don't have "check every" or "refresh every" options checked under subversion.

Basically I never want Intellij to stop checking the whole project and server every time I make a small change to a file.

Answer (score 0):

> When you click the version control tab at the bottom of the IDE and look at local changes, the lists often say "Updating...".

This means IDE is refreshing the local status of the files to correctly show them in the Local changes and other respective places. It is not related to remote servers.

It could take long because of e.g. huge number of unversioned files in the project. In this case, adding them to `svn:ignore` should help.